# What is "Document" keyword and ".something" means?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this code:

```
Public static List <LinkNode> parse (LinkNode inputLink) {

List <LinkNode> outputLinks = new LinkList<>();

try { 
Document parsedResults = Jsoup
.connect (inputLink.getUrl ())
.timeout (READ_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISSECS)
.get ();
}

String tag;
Elements elements;
List <LinkNode> result;
}
```

I have few questions about the code:

1. Is `Document` a reserved keyword Java?

   ```
   try { 
   Document parsedResults = Jsoup
   .connect (inputLink.getUrl ())
   .timeout (READ_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISSECS)
   .get ();
   ```
2. What is this form of coding (dot something)? Can I write it in another form If yes can you show me how?

   ```
   .connect (inputLink.getUrl ())
   .timeout (READ_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISSECS)
   .get ();
   ```

Comment: What kinda of editor/ide are you using? A good ide can provide you with helpful hints and context assists. #2 - method calls in a [fluent api](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java)

Comment: Am using eclipse. #2 can I write it in formal way like something.someObject ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, it is not a reserved keyword. In this case, `Document` is the name of a class defined in the Jsoup library. Other libraries can have their own class named `Document`, or you could write your own. For example:

   [image]

   In contrast, reserved keywords cannot be used as identifiers (i.e. class names, function names, variable names). These words include **class**, **try**, **if**, **while**, **public**, **private**, and more. See a bigger list [here](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/j/java_reserved_words.htm).
2. The dot (.) operator allows you to access an object's functions or variables. For example `rectangle.width` or `dog.run()`.

   Your example shows method chaining, in which subsequent methods are called on the object returned by the previous method. This removes the need for creating intermediate variables and makes things easier (for you as a programmer and also someone that is reading your code).

   You could achieve exactly the same result with more code:

   ```
   Connection conn1 = Jsoup.connect(inputLink.getUrl ());
   Connection conn2 = conn1.timeout(READ_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISSECS);
   Document parsedResults = conn2.get();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1) No, it's a class defined in the Jsoup library.

2) It's part of a normal method call, as in `Integer.parseInt("5")` or `scanner.readLine()`.

Comment: I think it would be worth mentioning chaining here. That is, following one method call, another call is made on the type returned by the first call.

Comment: @JamesB can you explain your idea in more details with an examples. Thanks